# Liskov Substitution Principle and strengthened validation?

Tags: c#, oop, liskov-substitution-principle

```
    public abstract class Entity 
    {
      public abstract IList<string> Values { get; set; }
    }

    public class GenericEntity : Entity 
    {
      private IList<string> _Values;
      public override IList<string> Values 
      {
        get { return _Values; }
        set 
        {
          ValidateValues(value);
          _Values = value;
        }    
      }
      protected virtual void ValidateValues(IList<string> values)
      {
        // many validation conditions here, if values validation fails, throws...
      }
    }

public class AEntity : GenericEntity 
{
  protected override void ValidateValues(IList<string> values)
  {
    base.ValidateValues(values);
    // there is an extra validation condition
    if(values.Count < 1) throw InvalidOperationException("values count!");
  }
}

public class BEntity : GenericEntity 
{
  protected override void ValidateValues(IList<string> values)
  {
    base.ValidateValues(values);
    if(values.Count < 2) throw InvalidOperationException("values count!");
  }
}
```

Is this a violation of the LSP for `GenericEntity` users when its inheritors have an extra validation conditions (checking the count of `Values` items)? I think so since preconditions have become strengthened.

Does it mean should I remove `GenericEntity` class and let both `AEntity` and `BEntity` be direct inheritors of `Entity`? But it will lead to repeated code in the two classes.

Also I consider another option: when `Entity` gets a referenece to some abstract class `Validation` instance. Is it the most elegant solution of the issue?

Comment: If `ValidateValues` is not semantically constrained in *how* it validates values (and the name suggests it isn't), then its validation is not a precondition, so the LSP does not apply. Whether or not you want to constrain them that way is up to you. The LSP is not a natural law. The real issue should be whether *callers* can reasonably be surprised about how validation happens and what is and is not allowed, and there is no general truth there. (This is also why "entities" are by far the worst thing to have in any application, since they communicate next to nothing.)

Answer (score 1):

Currently not "violating LSP" totally because you do not alter the class base validations. 
Unfortunately, Other developpers can override `ValidateValues` without calling base method...

A solution to avoid this is to create a two methods :

```
    public void ValidateValues(IList<string> values) {
        // many validation conditions here, if values validation fails, throws...
        ValidateValuesEx();    
    }

    protected virtual void ValidateValuesEx() {
        // for extension
    }
```

Comment: "because you do not alter the class base validations" - that's not really the reason and not really true, though. See Jeroen's comment.

Comment: The rule for LSP is "All subtype S of T, Then T can be replaced by subtype withtout altering desirable properties". LSP in a way/guidelines to avoid code changing and enforce code extension. The @Jeroen's comment is absolutely true, I don't take part of the "logic" code, and that's true that I answer technically to the question without taking other thing in account. Thanks for to point this.

Comment: "Subtype Requirement: Let ϕ ( x ) be a property provable about objects x of type T. Then ϕ ( y ) should be true for objects y of type S where S is a subtype of T." (Wikipedia) -> "provable" is the point here, I think. If you say "the setter will do validation, checking a,b,c" then this is a provable property. If you say "the setter will include some validation determined by the respective implementation" then it's not provable. You couldn't write a test for that.

Comment: Oh, I never think about this rule like that, or my comprehension of english put me in the wrong way. Thanks for this clarification

Answer (score 0):

With your code design, a sub-class could completely bypass your validation by not calling `base.ValidateValues`.  I don't know if this is a LSP-violation, but it is something you should consider.  If you make a small change, you can ensure that the validation that happens in `GenericEntity.ValidateValues` gets called every time.

```
public class GenericEntity : Entity 
{
    private IList<string> _Values;
    public override IList<string> Values 
    {
        get { return _Values; }
        set 
            {
                ValidateValues(value);
                _Values = value;
            }    
        }
        private void ValidateValues(IList<string> values)
        {
            // many validation conditions here, if values validation fails, throws...
            this.OnValidateValues(values);
        }
        protected virtual void OnValidateValues(IList<string> values)
        {
            //do nothing.  Let sub-classes override.
        }
    }
}

public class AEntity : GenericEntity 
{
    protected override void OnValidateValues(IList<string> values)
    {
        if(values.Count < 1) throw InvalidOperationException("values count!");
    }
}
```

In this code, the GenericEntity controls the call to the sub-classes' validation code.  Not the other way around.  The parent class validation is guaranteed to always run, and it always happens before any sub-class validation.

Note that the code works exactly the same whether or not the sub-class calls `base.OnValidateValues`.

Comment: Unfortunately this is only good for direct descendants -- `AEntity` now has the same problem for any classes inheriting from that. There is a "fix", but it's not pretty: make `OnValidateValues` sealed in `AEntity`, and call a new virtual `OnValidateValuesButMoreSo` method from it, repeat as necessary for more layers. If a deeper inheritance hierarchy isn't wanted, making `AEntity` sealed is another option. Otherwise, it really does become more attractive to go for a new `Validation` class, since you can enforce the same "must call base" restriction easier with constructors.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, just so I understand, are you saying that the Entity constructors should take a list of Validation objects?  And then `AEntity` simply needs to supply a list of Validation objects when calling its base constructor?  Does that mean that you must create `AEntity` and its specific ValuesCount validator separately?  If so, that makes me wonder what the point of this Entity class hierarchy is in the first place.

Comment: No, I'm not saying anything of the "should" kind. My code bases don't have `Entity` classes and I find it hard to reason about these super-generic cases. My only point was that constructors would be a natural fit for this pattern where derived validation must only strengthen base validation and should never bypass it -- I did not think about how you would integrate such validation objects into the current hierarchy. You could also use a chain of responsibility pattern. Or you could simply decide to not derive the hierarchy further than one level. Or you could tell inheritors to behave.